# MySQL query with multiple joins has slow performance in React js App

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I had just one table before called `user` table and all values were hard coded. **The query used to be faster.**
This is how my table used to be before:

```
id  username  religion     caste         gender
1   abc       Christian    catholic      Male
2   ahh       Hindu        caste 27      Female
3   hhh       Muslim       caste 73      Female
```

---

**Now** I have separate tables for religion and caste as shown below and the query takes much longer. I have the following tables:

users

```
id  username  religion     caste         gender
1   abc       1            1             Male
2   ahh       2            27            Female
3   hhh       3            73            Female
```

options_religion

```
rel_id       religion
1            Christian
2            Hindu
3            Muslim
4            Buddhist
.....
```

options_caste

```
cas_id      caste
1           catholic
2           orthodox
3           caste 3
4           caste 4
....
```

I have a query that selects users and gets their religion and caste using LEFT JOIN.

```
  const findProfilesWithFilter = await db.query(
`SELECT users.id, users.username, users.gender,
options_religion.religion, options_caste.caste
FROM users
LEFT JOIN options_religion ON users.religion = options_religion.rel_id
LEFT JOIN options_caste ON users.caste = options_caste.cas_id
WHERE
users.${language} = ${db.escape(l)} AND
users.${religion} LIKE ${db.escape(r)} AND
users.${gender} LIKE  ${db.escape(g)}
ORDER BY users.id DESC LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0`
```

)

The above query works and I get the religion and caste returned but it is much slower than simply hard coded values in my users table.

1. Is my query bad ?
2. Was it a better idea to keep all values hard coded in `users` table ? I was trying to save size.
3. How can I improve the performance of the query ?

I use this in my reactjs App. MYSQL is the database.

Answer (score 0):

These are some improvements you could implement in your query to improve performance:

1. Make sure your additional tables  `options_religion` and `options_caste` have an index (may be PRIMARY index) over `rel_id` and `cas_id` to optimize the join.
2. Avoid using LIKE if you filter using the whole name it will be better to use `=` for index performance. Otherwise, you need an index over the field to allow subtring search performance.
3. If you want to filter using the religion name (not id), use the new table `options_religion` instead of `users` (remember that religion in user is now an integer). Also, if you plan to filter using any of the additional tables, you can change the join to INNER JOIN.
4. The field users.gender could have a limited number of values, it will be more efficient if you filter using equals and whole word values "Male", "Female", etc.
5. In general when you are getting some performance issues, you can execute a "EXPLAIN" of you SQL query (using literal values instead of variables):    `EXPLAIN SELECT users.id, users.username, users.gender, ...`. The result of this explain tells you how many rows are involved in your query. If you see more than one row with a big number in "rows", probably you need some extra indexes.

Also, to make sure *is not a front-end problem* (too many rows to display, bandwidth) , try to test your query directly in the database console or client, and check the query time.

Comment: 1) Added index.. 2) Changed to - where possible. Could not do it for religion as I have "Any" search criteria that looks for `religion like %`. So I had to use LIKE.... 3) I did not understand this. I need to query users table and filter users by what is selected in the search form. I dont think I can query `options_religion` directly or may be I dont understand..... 4) I have 1 and 2 so I used = for gender....... Now the query is much faster and results load almost instantly (0.0048 seconds). I think index was the main issue.

Comment: Great news! Only in the 3rd point it's for improving performance in LIKE conditions (text search) creating a simple index over the text field (`CREATE INDEX idx_rel ON options_religion (religion)`) but it's only needed if you are planing to search for a substring in religion name `options_religion.religion` and there is a big list of rows inside

Answer (score -1):

it is a mysql performance issue. check if you have indices on the join field. Normally, you should not query the mysql directly in reactApp, use store procedure and wrapped in REST service or expose it as graphql service.

limit 500 is too aggressive, if you do have lots of records (like 500) to return, think about paging the recordsets. try set limit to 10 see if you app runs faster.

Comment: A suggestion for checking indexes should be a comment, not an answer. And you're also suggesting a different implementation (stored procedure, graphql), without even knowing root cause. The OP shouldn't be rewriting to build a REST / graphql service without even knowing their performance issue (which won't be solved by adding an API layer).

Comment: I am not using GraphQL but I have the query in a stored proc (The react App calls the server to query).. I do not think GraphQL is necessary but yea it has benefits. `SHOW INDEX FROM options_religion` returned nothing. I am new to MYSQL .. Is that the correct query to find if there are indices ?

Comment: I mean normal best practice, did not suggest you use middle-tier service. try to run the query directly in mysql console to if you get the right results. you should fetch 10 first, when they click next, then fetch next 10 and so on.... if you return 500, but user may never scroll to next page, 490 records will be wasted.

Comment: I have 500 but I am loading 10 at a time using Redux state. There is a load more button that updates the state.. I am fetching 500 so that there is only one query made.